# Face authentication is not working in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, biometrics

In my application, I am using biometric authentication (fingerprint and face authentication). Fingerprint authentication is working as expected. **But for face authentication (Even hardware support for face authentication), it shows the response that the biometric is not enrolled**.

Used the below code to check the **availability of biometric hardware** in device

```
biometricFeatures = new List<string>();
PackageManager packageManager = Application.Context.PackageManager;
if (packageManager != null)
{
    string feature = string.Empty;
    if (packageManager.HasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FeatureFace))
         biometricFeatures.Add(BiometricType.FACE.ToString());
    if (packageManager.HasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FeatureFingerprint))
         biometricFeatures.Add(BiometricType.FINGERPRINT.ToString());
}
```

Tested the face authentication in following android devices

Face authentication **working device**

- Samsung M51 (android 10)
- Realme (android 10)

Face authentication **not working devices**

- Samsung M01 (android 10)
- Honor 8X (android 10)
- Honor 9Lite (android 9)

Below is the piece of code used to check the **enrollment of biometric** options in device

```
var biometricManager = BiometricManager.From(currentContext);
var biometricEnrolledState = biometricManager.CanAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BiometricWeak);
if (biometricEnrolledState == BiometricManager.BiometricErrorNoneEnrolled)
    return false;
else if (biometricEnrolledState == BiometricManager.BiometricSuccess)
    return true;
```

Comment: have you seen this? https://source.android.com/security/biometric